# How to optimize laravel queues?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

My Laravel Queue has 1 Million Job. Each job takes 5-6 Seconds to execute. ( I am fetching web page as html. Storing html data in database and also mailing this data).
So it would take around 50-60 days to execute.
How can I optimize it? 
I am using database as queue_driver.

Comment: Well I don't think that's enough details to figure out why it takes so long to execute...

Comment: I am fetching HTML content from a web page and storing it in database and Mailing it to users.

Comment: This question isn't answerable. It depends on what your queue is doing, how you've decided to implement it, and countless external factors like server load or network performance.

Comment: Can you please just tell me how I can execute multiple jobs from one queue?

Comment: Start more workers if the machine can take it

Answer (score 0):

Push you jobs to several queues with their own workers. You also can add extra workers for every queue.

Comment: Can you tell me I can do that??

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up several queues that will serve as buckets and additionally each queue should have several workers on them. I would also explore using something like AWS SQS. You can read more about using workers [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#running-the-queue-listener).

Comment: Can you tell me I can do that??